# Is $\mathbb{N}$ definable in $(\mathbb{Z},0,S)$?

Tags: logic, model-theory

Is the subset of natural numbers (first-order) definable in the structure $(\mathbb{Z},0,S)$ ($S$ is the successor function)? I believe that it cannot, since $\mathbb{N}$ is exactly the set of elements 'reachable' from $0$ by applying $S$, but cannot find a precise argument. The only automorphism of the structure $(\mathbb{Z},0,S)$ is the identity, which of course preserves every subset.

Comment: @AsafKaragila my mistake, I'll delete.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint.** Show that $\mathrm{Th}(\mathbb Z,0,S)$ has quantifier elimination. Then enumerate the atomic formulas: from here, show that no boolean combination defines $\mathbb N$.